# Overlapping backgrounds cause unwanted borderline

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools, brush

I'm trying to hide the borderline between the overlapping differently colored backgrounds. Has anybody a tip how to deal with this:

[image]

I have tried the brush tool, but the result wasn't acceptable.

Thanks and great day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dodge Tool can be great for these cases. Select it, set it to use a soft edge brush and set Exposure to something as high as 60%, but leave Protect Tones. Use it to lighten the gray areas, being careful to not lighten the image itself.

If the gray is still visible disable Protect Tones and do your best to keep away from the models, as it'll lighten the colors very quickly.

Comment: Wow Wow Wow Thank you so much, Learned a lot from both of you guys, much appreciation Have a great day all :) 

one more question doe: Im having trouble as well with those specific pictures to isolate the object from the background especially in the hear section because its bright blonde, iv tried many approches including calculations but none of them work as well am I the only one who thinks that this kind of image as a complex image to isolate?

Again thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Dont Forget to accept the answer if it helped ;) Isolating hair can be tricky for a computer...you best bet would be to do it manually with the Lasso Tool

Comment: @osherez I'll add my voice to SitiSchu's: Use Lasso Tool to protect areas that shouldn't be touched. No tricks will fully preserve the image, you need to do this manually. However, if you can tolerate a alteration in the image using channels is worth a shot. This approach depends a lot on the image tones. You'll likely use adjustment layers like curves, levels or selective color to darken the light tones of the image without darkening the background too much, maybe a mask or two, then channels to select the background. It's complex work, but worth learning.

Comment: Again Guys, Thank you so much for the kind help I didn't a expected that much of useful and professional info, so much appreciation you all rock :)
**Im new to stack exchange and Im not sure If im doing things right Iv clicked on the check mark to accept nothing happen, Do I need to do something else for you guys?

Comment: @osherez Welcome to SE! Accepting an answer works just like this, you tick the check mark and that's it. I advise you to upvote every helpful comment and answer if you're not doing it already. The answers below rock and deserve more upvotes. They're more versatile than mine, which works for white backgrounds only.

Answer (score 4):

Blur the border. Make a selection that covers the area where you want the smooth transition occur. Goto Filter > Blur > Motion blur, direction = 0 degrees. Put the preview on and move the slider for the wanted effect.

Gaussian Blur does not work here because it makes the top and bottom easily thin. You want the blur only horizontally.

Here's the selection, blur dialog and the preview of the result.

[image]

Another option is to remove the backgrounds totally and put a new that fits to the general design. It needs much work, but it's in wide use due it's great possiblities.

Comment: Wow Wow Wow Thank you so much, Learned a lot from both of you guys, much appreciation Have a great day all :) 

one more question doe: Im having trouble as well with those specific pictures to isolate the object from the background especially in the hear section because its bright blonde, iv tried many approches including calculations but none of them work as well am I the only one who thinks that this kind of image as a complex image to isolate?

Again thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have both these images on different layers, in my opinion, the best way to do this would be with a layer mask - since it's non-destructive. Non-destructive editing techniques are the way to go if you need to edit the image differently in the future, since the original image is unaffected.

Here I have set up a white background layer, with the images on two layers above. The top layer has a layer mask applied, which I edited with a large soft edged brush set to black.

[image: Example showing arrangement of layers and mask]

Now, because it is masked out, you can easily drag the right side image over to the left, to get rid of the extra space.

[image: Example moving the masked layer]

Comment: wow wow very cool Idea bro Liked It alot :) thank you appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach based specifically on these images... This method may or may not be acceptable in your case

- Press the <kbd>M</kbd> key to activate the Rectangular Marquee Tool and drag a selection around one of the images (drag past and use the <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keys to nudge to the edge):

[image: Marquee is a funny word]

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to Paste in place
- Go to Edit > Transform > Flip Horizontal
- Right-click on a layer and select 'Merge Visible'

This gives us a transition which is not as harsh, and so gives us a little bit better starting point that we may come up with better results:

[image: A softer transition to begin with]

Now we'll perform essentially the same operation as user287001 has in their answer above, except instead of motion blur I used Box Blur:

[image: Blurring the line]

And the final result:

[image]

Comment: Hey, @BANG, Like mentioned before  wow wow wow, You all Truly amazing, So much appreciation. You all gave me tools for my next projects. thanks thanks and again  thank you. Keep it up so happy Iv joined this community :)